# "Bad property protocol declaration" Error with JSONModel library

Tags: ios

I have a simple JSON like this:

```
{
    description = "Skill description",
    languages = [
                {
                 name = iOS,
                 skillLevel = 6
                },
                {
                name = Android,
                skillLevel = 4
                }
    ]
}
```

and I need to create a model using JSON Model.

My model looks like this:

**SkillModel.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <JSONModel/JSONModel.h>

@protocol LanguageModel
@end

@interface SkillModel : JSONModel

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//  SkillModel
//

//
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *description;

//
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<LanguageModel> *languages;

@end



// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//  LanguageModel
//
@interface LanguageModel : JSONModel

//
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;

//
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *skillLevel;

@end
```

And the other code looks like this:

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *mobileSkillsDic = ...Dict data from json file....;
SkillModel *skillModel = [[SkillModel alloc] initWithDictionary:mobileSkillsDict error:&error];
```

What I'm doing wrong? I'm getting this error:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Bad property protocol declaration, reason: LanguageModel is not allowed JSONModel property protocol, and not a JSONModel class.**

Comment: I assume you are building `JSONModel` along with your project (i.e. it's a separate Xcode target)?  If so just add an exception breakpoint and it will break within the bit of the `JSONModel` code that is throwing this exception.  This should provide a clue (for either you or us).

Comment: I'm building JSONModel along my project

Comment: Solved!I've created the classes in different files and it works :)